# How to set JInternalFrame's size

Tags: java, windows, macos, jframe, jinternalframe

i have a JFrame in which i set the content pane with a JDesktopPane.

```
jDesktopPane1 = new JDesktopPane();
setContentPane(jDesktopPane1);
```

My JFrame is full screen size, when i add a JInternalFrame with size 300x300

```
Main.getInstance().setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
c = new Clients();
c.setVisible(true);
setEnabled(true);
Main.getInstance().addInDesktop(c);
```

In Clients:

```
this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 300));
```

On my mac osx all works fine, if i use it on a windows machine the jinternalframe takes fullscreensize even if i set size or preferredsize. What can i do? It's possible all this changes between the two os?

[image: This is a windows view]

[image: This is a MacOsX view]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
setMaximumSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
setMaximizable(true);
```

work for me!

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to the [InternalFrameDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/InternalFrameDemoProject/src/components/InternalFrameDemo.java) in Oracle's Documentation.  Your program may not be set up in the same manner as this example, but it should definitely help.  I was able to get the program to work properly and I have a Windows OS.

Also, be sure to include these lines of code in `createMethod()` before `frame.setVisible(true);` if you want to refer to this example.

```
// Set your preferred size and location here
frame.setSize(x,y);
frame.setLocation(x,y);
```